# Protect my Android (Intel XDK) app from piracy

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk, piracy, piracy-protection

I´ve been developing an Android app with Intel XDK but now I need to know how can I protect it from piracy.

Can you tell me the methods to achieve this and how can apply it with Intel XDK? (any example will be useful)

Just in case, my app will work with and without internet connection.

I´m new with this kind of security issues.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience building HTML5 apps with Intel XDK there are a couple of measures you can take.. The first one is to conceal the logic that may be in the javascript by making it unfeasible to understand it. This is called obfuscation and you should choose the most resilient option you can find. Most obfuscators are trivial to reverse so check carefully. On top of this, you can apply RASP capabilities such as anti-debugging and anti-tampering transformations. This makes your javascript protect itself basically. I'm using [Jscrambler](https://www.jscrambler.com) to achieve this and AFAIK it is the only solution that is offering these possibilities. I found them through some blog post they posted once..take a look

Comment: Thanks Josh, thats useful but do you have a advice to avoid account creations from users that not purchased the app?

Comment: You could send users a link after they paid to create their account, instead of creating accounts inside the app.
You could also verify each user through the transaction id of their payment.